# How to do OnCollisionExit in Character Controller - Unity 3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collider

I am a beginner in unity and I am having a problem with how to do the `OnCollisionExit` in `OnControllerColliderHit`. What I want to do is to detect the collision and make the object appear by setting the `SetActive` to true and then setting the `SetActive` to false to make it disappear again upon exiting the collision or contact with the object. Generally, I just want to know how to do the `OnCollisionEnter` and `OnCollisionExit` when using `OnControllerColliderHit`.

Here is my code:
using UnityEngine;

```
public class PlayerCollision : MonoBehaviour
{
    public PlayerMovement movement;
    [SerializeField] GameObject _toggleObject;

    private void OnControllerColliderHit(ControllerColliderHit hit) {
        if(hit.gameObject.tag == "Obstacle")
        {
            _toggleObject.SetActive(true);
        }else
        {
            _toggleObject.SetActive(false);
        }
    }
```

Comment: If a thing isn’t active. It can’t be hit. So wont be able to be activated. You can turn off the renderer to “hide” it but not effect the colliders. I’m not sure what oncontrollercolliderhit is supposed to be

Comment: it is the collision detector callback for Character Controller.